# Does ios have any notification when background tasks ended?

Tags: ios, background-process

I'm dowloading a mp3 file when the app is in background.  Does iOS have any notifications when background tasks ended?

Comment: Ehat do you mean by notification? NSNotification? Local Notification? Operation callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSNotificationCenter to send a notification to some part of your code when your download is finished.

I'm guessing you are using NSURLConnection to download your Mp3, you can then register a new notification while you are starting the download and when the download is finished (maybe in the delegate of NSURLConnection) you'll be able to post the notification.

Hope this is helpful

[NSNotification Center Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[NSURLConnection Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

For tasks that need to run in the background, you should use

```
- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void (^)(void))handler;
```

The "handler" will be called upon completion of the task.

Hope this helps.